# Detecting/avoiding multiple apt-get/dpkg installs

Tags: bash, ubuntu, debian, apt, dpkg

I have scripts that new-users run to configure their system, basically a bash script with a big for loop like so:

```
DEBCOUNT=${#DEBS[@]}
for (( i=0; i<${DEBCOUNT}; i++ ));
do
  PACKAGE=${DEBS[$i]}
  dpkg -s ${PACKAGE} >> /dev/null
  if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 ]; then
    echo -n  =========== Installing ${PACKAGE}
    echo "  ( $((${i}*100/${DEBCOUNT}))% )"

    apt-get -qq install -y --force-yes  ${PACKAGE}
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo ERROR: Failed to install required package ${PACKAGE}
      exit 1
    fi
  else
    echo -n  =========== Skipping ${PACKAGE}
    echo "  ( $((${i}*100/${DEBCOUNT}))% )"
  fi
done
```

The big `DEBS` array is a list of 50-ish packages to install on a fresh system (mostly compilers and editors).

It works great, except in the case where some system process kicks in and starts updating APT databases in the background.. Then it fails with `dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process`.

Is there an elegant/robust way to avoid this error? Either through detecting it and somehow waiting until it's free, or through preventing it in the first place.

**Responses**

- I don't want to just remove the lockfile. Trying to install my stuff and whatever the system does at the same time will inevitably break something.
- I can't do a single check on start, as what I'm seeing seems to indicate that the other process *is* doing the kind of wait I want, and jumping in between two of my `apt-get`'s.
- It's not a single process doing the lock.. Sometimes I think it's the ubuntu software updater, sometimes I think it's a `cron` job running a big `apt-get update` .

Comment: why not use all the packages in one shot using `apt-get`  instead of installing packages one after another? Also, `--force-yes` is certainly something I will always avoid as you will be overlooking the underlying problem while forcing your way through.

Comment: you can't install two packages at the same time on Ubuntu.

Comment: The big command was the original design, but a few packages come from PPA's and left the system in weird states if they failed to install.. Users wound up left with half the packages installed, and half not, and it wasn't easy to figure out which ones were missing.  This is safer (albeit slower).

Comment: @avinash Duh.. that's kinda the point of the question.. how do I prevent another process from doing it? Or how do I detect it, and know when it's safe?

Comment: Not sure how efficient is this, but try running `rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock` immediately before `apt-get ...` command in the `for` loop. That way, you will kill the lock (if any) before running the package install.

Comment: Work-around: `until dpkg -s ${PACKAGE} >> /dev/null; do sleep 1; done` ? Perhaps check the actual `$?` value, in case package-reinstall returns error...

Comment: Why dont you just ckeck before running the scipt if youbuntu updater is in ps -ef, and kill it with -15 level.

Answer (score 4):

I came here with the same question of wanting to detect whether the lock file used by `apt-get` and `dpkg` is locked, leaving aside whether this is the most relevant test to perform (it is in my case). I ended up using the following snippet of Python code:

```python
import fcntl

def is_dpkg_active():
    """
    Check whether ``apt-get`` or ``dpkg`` is currently active.

    This works by checking whether the lock file ``/var/lib/dpkg/lock`` is
    locked by an ``apt-get`` or ``dpkg`` process, which in turn is done by
    momentarily trying to acquire the lock. This means that the current process
    needs to have sufficient privileges.

    :returns: ``True`` when the lock is already taken (``apt-get`` or ``dpkg``
              is running), ``False`` otherwise.
    :raises: :py:exc:`exceptions.IOError` if the required privileges are not
             available.

    .. note:: ``apt-get`` doesn't acquire this lock until it needs it, for
              example an ``apt-get update`` run consists of two phases (first
              fetching updated package lists and then updating the local
              package index) and only the second phase claims the lock (because
              the second phase writes the local package index which is also
              read from and written to by ``dpkg``).
    """
    with open('/var/lib/dpkg/lock', 'w') as handle:
        try:
            fcntl.lockf(handle, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
            return False
        except OSError:
            return True
```

Comment: The IOError should be an OSError now:
Changed in version 3.3: Operations in this module used to raise an IOError where they now raise an OSError.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html

Comment: I've updated the code sample to use `OSError` instead of `IOError`, thanks for the suggestion @falcojr!

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution is to replace your complex script with a dummy package which `Depends:` in all the other packages you want installed.

The `equivs` package is an easy (albeit at first not very intuitive) way to build such a dummy package.

This isn't an ad-hoc hack, by the way; this is how e.g. the Debian `build-essential` package pulls in the entire build chain.

Comment: Can you say more about the "Depends:" setup? Is that a config somewhere? Is that some special package setting? How do I use this or where can I find more information?

Comment: It's a declaration in the `debian/control` file in the source of the package you build. Really, check out the [`equivs` documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/equivs-build.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

@tripleee's answer is the best one, but if for some reason you can't do that (and I know that in some rare cases that is true--because it happens for us), the proper thing is to issue a single command, rather than using a loop:

```
apt-get -qq install -y --force-yes $DEBS
```

Comment: Well, that still doesn't fix the main problem:  Even a single massive apt-get will fail if the Software Updater or a cron job is updating the APT database in the background.  Is there a way to detect that APT is already in use and wait?

Comment: The best option, then, would be to run in a loop, and if you detect a failure, try again. If you detect success, then exit the loop.

Comment: Well some failures are catastrophic: (cannot resolve dependency, server is down, etc).. I just want to detect one easy one: (cannot obtain lock).

Comment: @Yeraze: You can determine that by examining the error output from apt-get and grepping, for instance, for the word 'lock'